# Javascript/HTML5 Image Viewer with Labels

Tags: javascript, image, html, annotations

I am reconstructing a massive collection of medical modules that were created in Flash. All of the modules are being redesigned for cross platform enjoyment (*js and HTML5*). I have been searching for a library or plugin that will add arrows(with rollover capabilities) and text above an image when the user clicks a button. I have had little luck.

The closest package I have found is [Zoomify](http://www.zoomify.com), but it's still not what I am looking for. They are asking for too much money for maximum development capabilities. I was really hoping to find a JQuery plugin or javascript library that would allow me to fully customize the interface. Here is a screenshot of an **OLD FLASH** module:

[image: Old Module]

The red arrow corresponds to the link selected on the left. The new design is much more appealing but the underlying idea is the same, click buttons point to the objects.

If there is no such library or plugin should I create a simple javascript image viewer and store overlay coordinates in a database? Or is that overkill? I have hunderds of these things to do... maybe thousands :( Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is provided by CSS, which enables one to place text directly on top of an image or other rendered HTML. The key CSS properties to investigate are:

- [position](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position) set to 'absolute'
- values for at least two of [top](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/top), [right](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/right), [bottom](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/bottom) or [left](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/left)
- use [z-index](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index) to specifying layering/order

Comment: That's a valid point. My concern is the amount of labels I have to add. 20 labels per image, over a thousand images. Is css and html the best approach?

Comment: HTML/CSS provides the display -- the runtime can be built using native JavaScript as you suggested in the original post. The coordinates might be a JSON-encoded string delivered via AJAX by a PHP/MySQL app, or might be a single JSON-encoded data file delivered directly to the client. The aim of my post was to point out that you do not really need a JavaScript or jQuery library to overlay onto an image given coordinates.

Comment: Sounds good! I will do some more research on AJAX and JSON. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) is a good option "Lightbox is a simple, unobtrusive script used to overlay images on top of the current page. It's a snap to setup and works on all modern browsers."